# How to make a GTK window scrollable?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I'm developing a program using GTK3, glade and C language, but in one of the windows i need to make only part of it scrollable (the size of the total scrollable area won't change), but i'm having a hard time with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtk/gtkx.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//login window
GtkBuilder  *builder;
GtkWidget   *window;
GtkWidget   *fixed1;
GtkWidget   *button1;
GtkWidget   *button2;
GtkWidget   *label1;
GtkWidget   *entry1;
GtkWidget   *entry2;
GtkWidget   *icon_entry;
GtkWidget   *image;

//register window
GtkWidget *r_window, *r_fixed;
GtkWidget *r_button1, *r_button2, *r_label;
GtkWidget *r_entry1, *r_entry2, *r_entry3;
GtkWidget *r_image;

//menu window
GtkWidget *menu_win, *menu_fixed;
GtkWidget *menu_button1, *menu_button2, *menu_button3;
GtkWidget *menu_button4, *menu_button5, *menu_button6;

//album window
GtkWidget *album_win,  *album_fixed;
GtkWidget *album_grid, *album_label1, *album_label2;
GtkWidget *album_view, *album_scroll;

//showing functions
void register_s (){
gtk_widget_show(r_window);
}
void login_s (){
gtk_widget_show(window);
}
void menu_s (){
gtk_widget_show(menu_win);
}
void album_s (){
gtk_widget_show(album_win);
}

//hiding functions
void register_h (){
gtk_widget_hide(r_window);
}
void login_h (){
gtk_widget_hide(window);
}
void menu_h (){
gtk_widget_hide(menu_win);
}
void album_h (){
gtk_widget_hide(album_win);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv); 
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file ("testing.glade");

//login window
window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "login_window"));
g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    fixed1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "fixed1"));
    label1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "label1"));
    entry1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "entry1"));
    entry2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "entry2"));
    image = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "image"));
    
    button1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button1"));
    g_signal_connect(button1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(register_s), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(button1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(login_h), NULL);
    
    button2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button2"));
    g_signal_connect(button2, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(menu_s), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(button2, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(login_h), NULL);
    
    
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

//register window
r_window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "r_window"));
g_signal_connect(r_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    r_button1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "r_button1"));
    
    r_button2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "r_button2"));
    g_signal_connect(r_button2, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(login_s), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(r_button2, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(register_h), NULL);
    
    r_entry1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "r_entry1"));
    r_entry2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "r_entry2"));
    r_entry3 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "r_entry3"));
    r_fixed = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "r_fixed"));
    r_label = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "r_label"));
    r_image = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "r_image"));

//menu window
menu_win = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "menu_win"));
g_signal_connect(menu_win, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
menu_fixed = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "menu_fixed"));

    menu_button1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "menu_button1"));
    g_signal_connect(menu_button1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(album_s), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(menu_button1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(menu_h), NULL);
    menu_button2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "menu_button2"));
    menu_button3 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "menu_button3"));
    menu_button4 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "menu_button4"));
    menu_button5 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "menu_button5"));
    menu_button6 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "menu_button6"));
    g_signal_connect(menu_button6, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

//album window
album_win = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "album_win"));
g_signal_connect(album_win, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
album_fixed = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "album_fixed"));

    album_grid = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "album_grid"));
    album_view = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "album_view"));
    album_scroll = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "album_scroll"));
    gtk_range_set_range (GTK_RANGE(album_scroll), 0, 600 );
    //g_signal_connect(album_scroll, "change-value", G_CALLBACK(), NULL);
    album_label1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "album_label1"));
    album_label2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "album_label2"));

//main functions

    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}//main
```

This is the code i've written so far, i want to keep it as simple as possible cause i'm working with people who don't know GTK.
[The current widgets added in glade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpSGM.png)
[The current design of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twlJl.png)

The thing is that i want to put images there, make one side (left of scrollbar) scrollable and displaying the photos and the other side immobile.
I'm new to programming, so i'd appreciate if you could explain it in a simple way.

Comment: Where do all those backslashes come from? `GtkWidget \*album_win ... `

Comment: Don't know, appeared when i put the code here.

Comment: For a minimum reproducible example do you really need all those callbacks?

Comment: No, these callbacks are being used for calling other windows (the program consists of multiple windows) i added them to explain better how the entire code is working.

Comment: Instead of using GtkFixed, you should be using horizontal box. For the scrolling view, you want to put the `album_vew` widget in a GtkScrolledWindow (which contrary to its name, is just a widget, not a window)